# How do I append the contents of a file to another file?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write something that takes the contents of a file and appends it to a different file.

```
if($x == 1) {take the contents of ./machines/x.txt and append to ./$engineer.txt;}
if($y == 1) {take the contents of ./machines/y.txt and append to ./$engineer.txt;}
if($z == 1) {take the contents of ./machines/z.txt and append to ./$engineer.txt;}
```

There's lots on here about appending, but I can't make any of it work with my script.

Comment: Have you read perldoc open? This is a trivial question. What have you tried, and why did it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`Path::Tiny` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) makes it easy, since it includes methods for appending to a file and for getting a file's contents:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Path::Tiny; # Install with your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client

my $source = path("file2.txt");
path("file1.txt")->append_raw($source->slurp_raw) if $source->exists;
```

---

If you can't use extra modules for some reason, you can manually open the destination file in append mode and write the contents of the input files to it:

```perl
if (-e "file2.txt") {
  open my $output, ">>:raw", "file1.txt"
    or die "Unable to open file1 for appending: $!\n";
  open my $input, "<:raw", "file2.txt"
    or die "Unable to open file2 for reading: $!\n";
  print {$output} <$input>; # Reads all lines since <> is in list context
}
```

---

Finally, for good measure, a subroutine that might perform better than the above because it works with blocks of raw data instead of lines:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/signatures/;
use POSIX qw/:stdio_h/;

sub append_to($destination, $source) {
  return unless -e $source;
  open my $output, ">>:raw", $destination
    or die "Unable to open $destination for appending: $!\n";
  open my $input, "<:raw", $source
    or die "Unable to open $source for reading: $!\n";

  while (sysread $input, my $block, BUFSIZ) {
    syswrite $output, $block;
  }
}

append_to "file1.txt", "file2.txt";
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, maybe because "file2.txt" is empty in the first instance?
`if ($Eschmann == 1) { path("./Manufacturers/Eschmann.txt")->append_raw(path("./$engineer.txt")->slurp_raw); }`

Comment: @PeteG Yeah, you'd have to add a check to see if the file you're trying to read from exists before trying to read it if it's possible that it doesn't.

Comment: Updated code to include checks like that.

Comment: Also based on the psuedocode in your question, you have the file names reversed in that if you're trying to append to `"$engineer.txt"`.

Answer (score -2):

I'd use qx

```
my $c= 'rm -f ./engineer.txt';
qx/$c/;
my $m = './machines';
$c = "cat $m/x.txt $m/y.txt $m/z.txt > engineer.txt";
qx/$c/;
if ($?) { print 'failed';} else {print 'succeeded';}
```

Comment: That looks more like shell than Perl.